# С помощью чего можно редактировать видио на сервере?

Tags: node.js, php, видео, html5, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, есть ли какие-нибудь готовые решения для редактирования видиофайлов на сервере? например обрезка видио, умеет ли php вообще работать с видио? вот например обрезать картинки и т.д. можно. Или вообще расскажите, на каком сервере можно это сделать если на php нельзя, (например на nodeJS можно?)

Comment: видЕо!!!...

Comment: php из коробки - нет. Но видео, как и практически любой другой медиа-файл - контейнер данных, который а) разбирается сторонними библиотеками (ffmpeg, есть расширение для php) и б) разбирается вручную (очень геморно, лучше это дело сразу отставить).
Ну и всегда остается самый кривой вариант - поставить ту или иную тулзу, котоаря умеет работать из командной строки (тот же ffmpeg умеет) и тянуть ее.

Answer (score 1):

[ffmpeg - офф сайт](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)

[habrahabr - простейшие команды для ознакомления](http://habrahabr.ru/post/171213/)

[phpClasses - набор готовых классов для работы с видео](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=ffmpeg&x=0&y=0&go_search=1)

Comment: https://packagist.org/search/?q=video тогда уж